# Straight Forecast Probability (Horse Racing)

Tags: probability

I have probabilities on four horses winning a race. Horse A =0.52, B=0.33, C= 0.11 and D=0.04.

What I want to do is find the straight forecast probability of Horse A winning and Horse B finishing second. I know there are 2! combinations for this to happen, but I'm not sure where to progress from here (or if it is possible). If the horses all had equal probabilities of winning I think it would be easier.

Can someone help out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part is figuring out the probability that Horse $B$ finishes second given that Horse $A$ finished first. It's no longer going to be $0.33$, since the $3$ probabilities of $0.33, 0.11, 0.04$ no longer sum to $1$, but $0.48$. To fix this, we can scale these $3$ probabilities by dividing each by $0.48$. (Note that this is a simplifying assumption; it's not guaranteed to work all the time.) This yields:
$$
P(A \text{ is first, } B \text{ is second}) = P(A \text{ is first})P(B \text{ is second} \mid A \text{ is first}) = (0.52) \left(\dfrac{0.33}{0.48}\right) = 0.3575
$$

Comment: Thanks Adriano, when is it not guaranteed to work? It is mathematically correct though isn't it (based on my college level probability knowledge)?

Comment: @clattenburgcake It may be the case, for example, that Horse $D$ is much much better at coming in second than coming in first. In that case, $P(D \text{ is second} \mid A \text{ is first})$ might not be $0.04/0.48$, but in fact closer to $0.99$.